# Are the hermeneutic principles used for support to facts known to chazal or they used to make new rules?

Tags: hermeneutics

It is my understanding that the hermeneutic principles are used as support to a list of masoretic facts that chazal had, is that true or did they use them to devise new rules? This is only with regards to halacha not Aggada.

Comment: See Rambam's Sefer HaMitzvos Shoresh Sheni with Ramban.

Comment: Wait what do you mean by "masoretic facts" and "new rules"? Matters of Jewish law?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I was really getting at is whether or not there was a "master list of facts",  that chazal had and the hermeneutic principles were there to preserve the items in this list, or perhaps the hermeneutic principles were used to develop new rules?